# PHP: Trying to insert Twilio response JSON into MySQL TEXT field, but string is being truncated, possibly before the insert

Tags: php, json, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

Wordpress 5.3.2 and PHP 7.2 on localhost.

I'm sending a Twilio sms, and capturing the response from Twilio, which is JSON.

I want to store the response, because in it are all kinds of goodies, like the send date-time stamp.

When I make a test file, and print_r the response, it is a rather large JSON object. Not sure I should even post it here, at 11,568 characters. Here's a partial output (Acct values have been slightly altered):

```
Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\MessageInstance Object
(
    [_media:protected] => 
    [_feedback:protected] => 
    [version:protected] => Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010 Object
        (
            [_accounts:protected] => 
            [_account:protected] => Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\AccountContext Object
                (
                    [_addresses:protected] => 
                    [_applications:protected] => 
                    [_authorizedConnectApps:protected] => 
                    [_availablePhoneNumbers:protected] => 
                    [_calls:protected] => 
                    [_conferences:protected] => 
                    [_connectApps:protected] => 
                    [_incomingPhoneNumbers:protected] => 
                    [_keys:protected] => 
                    [_messages:protected] => Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\MessageList Object
                        (
                            [version:protected] => Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010 Object
 *RECURSION*
                            [solution:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [accountSid] => AC3365f6c6dddaac48edfb902a3e1b8688d
                                )

                            [uri:protected] => /Accounts/AC3365f6c6dddaac48edfb902a3e1b8688d/Messages.json
                        )

                    [_newKeys:protected] => 
(etc., etc...)
```

My test code looks like this:

```
$data['numbers'] = array( "9541234567");// phone numbers of sms recipients. Just one for now.
$count = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($data['numbers']);$i++){
    $args = array(
                    'number_to' => $data['numbers'][$i],
                    'message'   => "This is a test.\n",
                 );
    $sent = twl_send_sms( $args );
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($sent);//This line outputs that beautiful, robust JSON string I am after.
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

...so far, so good. The Twilio sms sends, and Twilio gives me a nice large response in JSON format.

Now, I transfer my code to the larger, production context, and I want to capture that 11,568 character JSON object, and store it in a table (by means of update). I think it should be a TEXT type, which is probably correct.

Here is my slightly revised code for production:

```
        $data['twilio_response'] = twl_send_sms( $args ); //This sends the sms, captures a Twilio response into an array element.
        $table = $wpdb->prefix . "npf_notifications";
        $data['notification-update'] = $wpdb->update(
                                                      $table, 
                                                      array('twilio_response' => $data['twilio_response']), 
                                                      array('id' => $data['notifications-insert']['id']), 
                                                      array('%s'),
                                                      array('%s')
                                                     );
        $data['notification-update-query'] = $wpdb->last_query; // this records the query in an array element, so I can examine it.
```

Unfortunately for me, I don't get anything near as complete as the raw JSON from my test script. Instead, my Twilio response JSON looks like this:

```
notification-update-query = UPDATE `xsdslp_npf_notifications` SET `twilio_response` = '[Twilio.Api.V2010.MessageInstance accountSid=AC3365f6c6dceec35edfb902a3e1b8688d sid=SMfeb33b00895e455091445e4901547e70]' WHERE `id` = '5e092437a6037_1577657399'
```

...and the value of the array element to which I assign my Twilio response data looks like (after printing it out using javascript):

```
$data['twilio_response'] = [Twilio.Api.V2010.MessageInstance accountSid=AC3365f6c6ddaac48edfb902a3e1b8688d sid=SMfeddaac485e455091445e4901547e70]
```

It looks like the MySQL update (or insert) isn't the problem, but the JSON response string is being shortened in my array element variable. Can someone out there tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: looks like you need to use json_encode() on $data['twilio_response'] first, because the returned object from twl_send_sms is not a JSON string, but a PHP object. Alternatively you can use serialize()

Comment: @AdrianEddy here's the result of json_encode($data['twilio_response']) : {}.

Comment: @AdrianEddy `serialize($data['twilio_response'])` worked. Thanks! Make an answer out of it, and I'll give you the green check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you need to use json_encode() on $data['twilio_response'] first, because the returned object from twl_send_sms is not a JSON string, but a PHP object. Alternatively you can use serialize()